# tkinter: the parents have children, but the children have no parents?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

So I am very new to this (please bear with me) and have looked for an answer to this extensively today. I have an issue with tkinter that I have not been able to find documented anywhere, which I have been able to reproduce on multiple files across multiple computers. here is a rather minimal block of code that shows the issue. It could be smaller, I think, but I wanted to give as much information as possible:

```
import tkinter as tk
import traceback

class Game:

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("800x600")
    root.resizable(False, False)
    quit = tk.IntVar()

    def __init__(self):
        self._root = Game.root
        self._hud = tk.Frame(master=self._root, bg="white", name="hud") #I have tried both setting the master and not setting the master
        self._active = tk.Frame(master=self._root, bg="white", name="active")
        self._active.place(relx=0.25, rely=0, relwidth=0.75, relheight=1)
        self._hud.place(relx=0, rely=0, relwidth=0.25, relheight=1)
        #NOTE I HAVE ALSO TRIED THIS WITH GRIDS AND IT HAD THE SAME RESULT


        def get_pathname():
            print(self._root.winfo_children(), "children of root.")
            for child in self._root.winfo_children():
                identity = child.winfo_id()
                parent = child.winfo_toplevel() #NOTE: I have also tried winfo_parent with the same result.
                print(parent, "is the parent of", child, "this should say root.")
                try:
                    child_path = child.winfo_pathname(identity)
                    print(child_path)
                except tk.TclError as e:
                    print(traceback.print_exc(), child, "traceback for child")
                    print(f"Error getting path for child with ID {identity}: {e}")
        hud_id = self._hud.winfo_id()



        if self._active.winfo_exists():
            print("It exists")
            active_id = self._active.winfo_id()
            print("I found the ID number:", active_id)
            self._active.update()
            self._root.after(500, lambda: get_pathname())
            self._root.mainloop()


game = Game()
```

When looking for the children of root, I get the following output

```
[<tkinter.Frame object .hud>, <tkinter.Frame object .active>] children of root.
```

But when I look for the parent of hud and active:

```
. is the parent of .hud
```

it then finds the ID of hud and immediately looks for its parent to create the path, but fails since hud is saying it has no parent (I think? The traceback isn't super clear) causing other things to fail. Most notably, I have a method that destroys every widget except named ones, but it  will always destroy hud and active due to this behavior.

I am sure I am doing something wrong, but this was my best guess on how to do this. Can anybody help me figure out how to fix this issue? Sorry if this should be in the other python tag, I asked a friend and they said to use this one!

Comment: `.` is simply the name of the root window - there's no way to assign a name of your own, like you can with widgets.  And note that `.winfo_toplevel()` returns the window containing the widget - which is not necessarily the parent, it could be an arbitrarily distant ancestor if your widgets are nested inside containers.  `.winfo_parent()` specifically gives you the parent.

Comment: Hm. Then I guess my best guess on the issue was wrong? Why is it failing to find the path? I guess that's the real issue. Thank you so much for the response!

Comment: You can simply use `parent = child.master` to get the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the parent of every child of the root window is `.`. `.` is the internal name of the root window, and it cannot be renamed.

Window paths are similar to a filesystem. Just like `/` is the root of a filesystem, `.` is the root of a window  hierarchy.